# Accidentally committed the .svn directory

Tags: svn

I accidentally committed a folder named `.svn` to a Subversion repository. Now when I try to check out or update I get this error message:

> svn: Failed to add directory
>   'oops/conferences/.svn': an
>   unversioned directory of the same name
>   already exists

I removed the directory in the next commit, but that didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: How is this related to git-svn?

Comment: @Daenyth: The `git-svn` tag at least explains how this could have happened. I don't think SVN would have allowed this. Also, this might mean that Patrick might not be familiar with SVN itself, which could be important for giving a good answer.

Comment: @Daenyth, @sbi: I created the mess by adding an .svn folder to a git repository. Then with `git-svn dcommit` I added it to a Subversion repository. Then I tried to update the working copy in another location using *only* svn. That's when I encountered the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried to remove the folder directly in the SVN repository?

```
svn delete http://my.svnserver.org/path/.svn
```

Most SVN commands can take either a local path into the working copy or an URL into the repository. You should be careful with the latter, since this performs the action directly, without any need to commit.

Answer (score 1):

svn revert back to the revision before you deleted the .svn folder.

See: http://wiki.greenstone.org/wiki/index.php/Useful_SVN_Commands

Answer (score 0):

Delete the folder and then update to the head revision.  Otherwise you may need to rebuild your repository I believe.  I'm not an expert but I've done this before.  I just fixed it be updating my repository.